# How to identify the javascript canvas library

Tags: javascript

How to identify the javascript canvas library used by a certain website? (e.g. processingjs or ...)

Comment: http://is.gd/6e0Ofo - not sure what these folks are using

Comment: use this if u wanna do it through javascript - http://code.google.com/p/library-detector/source/browse/branches/Daiquiri/embedded_scripts/libraries_test.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, install firebug. On the `net` tab, and `js` subtab, you will find all the library loaded. And also install `library-detector` add-on to determine which library is used.

And make sure, `net` is enabled.

[image: library-detect]

Answer (score 1):

View source or use firebug to view the included scripts.  If you see 'processing.js', for example, it may be used.  If you don't see it, well, it still may be used.

You have to dig into the included scripts to be sure.

**EDIT:**

Loos like IXL uses YUI to for general javascript utilities/DOM help/namespacing.  As far as I can tell, no canvas library was used -- basic shapes aren't that hard to draw with canvas.